# Change phone mode to vibrate using checkbox

Tags: android

In my application i want to use a functionality which can make the vibrate mode of phone disable or unable. I want to do it through checkbox, i.e. if i click the checkbox, it changes its mode into vibrate visa versa. Any thoughts ??

Comment: add your code here...what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this using AudioManager as:

```
 CheckBox  beijing=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.beijing);
// USE AudioManager  for Settingringing from vibration
                        AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    beijing.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){ 
                @Override 
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, 
                        boolean isChecked) { 
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                    if(isChecked){ 


                        switch (am.getRingerMode()) {   
                            case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:   
                                Log.i("MyApp","NORMAL mode");
                                am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
                                break;   
                        } 
                    }else{ 
                        switch (am.getRingerMode()) {   
                            case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:   
                                Log.i("MyApp","VIBRATE mode");
                                am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                                break;   
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
            });
```

Comment: The code is running fine, you can use it in future. Just make a small change on last swich-case, change Log.i("MyApp","NORMAL mode");
to Log.i("MyApp","VIBRATE mode"); for avoiding any printing confusion.